# How to set instance name for gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, i3-wm

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with i3. Many terminal applications have an option `-n` to set their instance name. I want to this so I can control a single terminal window which I have previously named 'asdf' with for_window [instance=asdf]. Is there a way to do this with gnome-terminal?

Comment: I managed to do a workaround where I used role instead. so basically `gnome-terminal --role=some_name`. And then instead use `for_window [window_role="some_name"]`

Comment: Thanks @miono that would probably work. I switched to kitty so don't have this issue anymore.